# Service Account Authentication for Google Cloud Storage works on some servers but not on other servers

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

Im using google-api-java-client to access the Google Cloud Storage API. It works fine from my local machine and from some servers. But it fails with a 400 Bad Request (error: invalid_grant) on production server. I had a similar problem with Google Adwords API which was solved by the Google API Adwords Support. I think they just whitelisted the IP's of the servers I used. 
Is it possible that I need to add permissions in the Google Cloud Storage API? Which would be strange, because it works from my local pc.

```
public class StorageObj {
    private static final String KEY_FILE_NAME = "key.p12";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "application_name";
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucket_name";
    private static final String STORAGE_OAUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private final Storage storageObject;

    public StorageObj() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(STORAGE_OAUTH_SCOPE))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_NAME))
                .build();

        this.storageObject = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        ;
    }

    public void insert(String folder, String file) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(folder + file))) {
            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream", inputStream);
            mediaContent.setLength(inputStream.available());
            Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject = storageObject.objects()
                    .insert(BUCKET_NAME, null /* obj-meta-data */, mediaContent)
                    .setName(file);

            int _2MB = 2 * 1000 * 1000;
            if (mediaContent.getLength() > 0 && mediaContent.getLength() <= _2MB) {
                insertObject.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(true);
            }
            insertObject.execute();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        new StorageObj().insert(args[0], args[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your service account might not have access to the cloud bucket's ACL. Maybe you have access to one bucket but not to all, so I think you might have the proper ACL for certain buckets, but not for others?

Also, when you say "local", do you mean the devserver? the google cloud storage behaves differently in devserver, so this might be explainable just with how the devserver works.

I also, in my answer, assumed that by "servers" you meant different buckets on the google cloud storage

Comment: by "servers" I mean digital ocean droplets. it wokrs from droplets in (digital ocean) amstardam 1 zone, but not in amsterdam 3 zone. We need to migrate to amsterdam 3 zone due to other considerations. We had similar problems with AdWords API and BigQuery API. Google Support whitelisted the IPs in Amsterdam3 zone, because the mapping was wrong. Now we can use these APIs from Amsterdam3 zone.